# CodeMirror & Chrome Extensions - issues adding local js files

Tags: google-chrome-extension, codemirror

I am trying to integrate CodeMirror's syntax highlighting with a textarea using chrome extensions.

Here is my **test.js**...

```
var srcArray = ["lib/codemirror.js", 
                "lib/util/matchbrackets.js", 
                "lib/util/continuecomment.js",
                "mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js",
                "mode/xml/xml.js",
                "mode/javascript/javascript.js",
                "mode/css/css.js",
                "mode/clike/clike.js",
                "mode/php/php.js"];             

function AddScript(value)
{
    var s = document.createElement("SCRIPT")
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL(value);
    s.onload = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    };
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);   

}   
srcArray.forEach(AddScript);
```

... and **manifest.json**:

```
{
"name":"Test",
"description":"Test description",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["file:///*Test*"],  
        "js": ["test.js"]
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": ["lib/codemirror.js", 
               "lib/util/matchbrackets.js", 
               "lib/util/continuecomment.js",
                "mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js",
                "mode/xml/xml.js",
                "mode/javascript/javascript.js",
                "mode/css/css.js",![enter image description here][1]
                "mode/clike/clike.js",
                "mode/php/php.js"]  
}
```

And here is the issue I am facing:

`<script>...</script>` are being added to the page, however when the last one is added they all disappear.

[image: From Chrome Dev Tools]

I suspect this has someting to do with security mechanisms introduced in 2nd version of the manifest. I cannot however figure out what is missing.

Your advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.